# How to open a WPF modal window if a method taking more time

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I am recently started to create a c# code to obtain the details or familiarize web-specific controls. In that code, I am having an XPath finding scenario, which may or may not take time based on the website. Now I am planning to have a scenario like, if the method is taking more than 10 sec to complete, I like to show a modal window saying the process is running. Why modal window is because I don't want the user to do anything in between the process. I created a WPF dialog box, now I need a proper code wise idea to implement this scenario. Like, if it taking more than 10 sec a dialog box will pop up and it will go once the XPath finding method is over.

Comment: Create a variable xPathComplete and set to false in the constructor.  Then set true after XPath is completed so you wait until XPath is finished before running any additional methods.

Comment: But that is not I wanted, I exactly want to show the pop up/dialog box only if the method exceeds 10 sec and not completed. Once it is completed, I will close the pop us well.

Comment: You still need the variable.  if you want a 10 second timeout the create a timer to wait up to 10 seconds.

Comment: even if I added a variable for a 10-second timeout, I want to show the popup and same I need the method to complete as well.

Comment: You need to block until the XPath completes.  You can use a waithandle or semaphore.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netcore-3.1